# Best/correct way to implement Master detail with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, master-detail

I'm implementing a Master/detail UI with Angular 4(Material Design) for Frontend and Rest API Node/MongoDB for Backend

First I've request to server the list of categories that `populate` their product `refs` and returns to Frontend via `JSON` all the data

My doubt is about when a user clicks on a list element:

```
-Pass whole data of the product to render it via `queryParams`

-Pass whole data of the product to render it via injected local Data service

-Pass id of the product via URL an then request the info to server again
```

Which would be the normal flow on app?

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though this is primarily opinion based, the best way to do this is to pass the id of the product via the `URL`. This way you can have a direct link to the product as well. You can obtain the data using a [`resolve guard`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard) service which can prefetch component data.

If you are worried about double requests and you should, you can create a caching service which obtains the results from a memory stored product collection, and if it cannot find it there, request the data from the server.

*untested example code*

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductCollectionCache {

    public readonly products: Product[] = [];

    public async getProduct(id: number): Promise<Product> {
       let product: Product = this.products.filter(p => p.id === id)[0];
       if (!product) {
           product = await this.productGetterService.getProduct(id);
       }
       return product;
    }

    public async getProductCollection(): Promise<Product[]> {
       //get collection or return cached
    }

}
```

On the other hand, if you are on the master form, you can obtain all the data from the server, and put this in the cache service

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then, the correct flow would be, On master request all data products and store it on cache service. When click on a item pass id of the product and OnInit of the detail component adquire the data from cache service. If data is not present on cache service it should request to remote data service to find the data. Is correct?

Comment: With complex product you could ask yourself if it's necessary to obtain all data in a master form. But it obviously depends on your situation. Besides that, you might want to look at using a `resolve` service (as mentioned in my answer) to obtain the data, so not in the `OnInit` of a component

Comment: Ok. With a resolve service in OnInit of detailComponent the data is already resolved and only need to get it via `this.route.data`. Is correct no?

Comment: That is correct. If you inject the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` in your component.

Comment: Is it a good way to store this temporaly data on a cookies (ng2-cookies)?

Comment: No, there is no reason to store this, it's no user data. Either cache the `GET` request using server side headers, or just obtain the data on every refresh.

Comment: but, in your example. If a user closes the navigator and then uses a favorite to access directly to a specific product detail, the cache will be empty because the memory has been cleared. It would request in this case to server no¿?

Comment: Indeed, that's the proper way to do it. You can however cache the GET result using headers from the server. But you shouldn't worry about that. What's the reason you don't want to have a server request when the user refreshes the page?

Comment: Only for avoid request to server. For example, when I request to server the categories of products, I populate their products refs with mongoose and then I have the data of the product. I think that request another time the product data is no necessary? Do you think that is better to request the details to server each time?